# Does SIV cause AIDS in primates... If not why

Tags: virology, human-evolution

does SIV cause AIDS in primates or have they developed resistance to the virus **

Comment: **Homework questions** and **trivial questions about basic biological concepts** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). This question can *easily* be answered by a Google search.

Comment: While the question doesn't show much effort, I'm not sure it looks like a homework question - and I certainly wouldn't call it a trivial question (apparently Nature agrees).

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simian_immunodeficiency_virus:

> Unlike HIV-1 and HIV-2 infections in humans, SIV infections in their
>   natural hosts appear in many cases to be non-pathogenic. Extensive
>   studies in sooty mangabeys have established that SIVsmm infection does
>   not cause any disease in these animals, despite high levels of
>   circulating virus. However, if this virus infects an Asian or Indian
>   rhesus macaque, the animal will develop simian AIDS (SAIDS).[5] A
>   recent study of SIVcpz in wild living chimpanzees suggests that
>   infected chimpanzees experience an AIDS-like illness similar to HIV-1
>   infected humans. The later stages of SIV infection turn into SAIDS,
>   much as HIV infection turns into AIDS.

Later in the article:

> Beatrice Hahn of the University of Pennsylvania and a team of
>   researchers in 2009 found that chimpanzees do die from simian AIDS in
>   the wild and that the AIDS outbreak in Africa has contributed to the
>   decline of chimpanzee populations. Testing wild chimpanzees,
>   researchers detected organ and tissue damage similar to late-stage
>   human AIDS. The infected chimpanzees had a 10 to 16 times greater risk
>   of dying than uninfected ones; infected females were less likely to
>   give birth, could pass the virus to their infants, and had a higher
>   infant mortality rate than uninfected females.

A couple of key references:

[Keele, B. F. et al. "Increased mortality and AIDS-like immunopathology in wild chimpanzees infected with SIVcpz" Nature 460, 515-519](http://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nature08200)

Commentary on the above: [Hayden, EK (2009) "Wild chimpanzees get AIDS-like illness" (DOI: 10.1038/news.2009.711)](http://www.nature.com/news/2009/090722/full/news.2009.711.html)

[Heeney J, Dalgleish A, Weiss R (2006) "Origins of HIV and the evolution of resistance to AIDS" Science 313(5786): 462–466](http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/reprint/313/5786/462.pdf)